# Changing Label text with Button click in VSCode

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have been creating an app in vscode and using c# for my language of choice. I know not the best environment but more for fun then anything so in this case not worried about that.

So I have been able to create a GUI and have all the labels and buttons setup as well as a 2nd file that I am using to store some data in. I have been able to get the button to work when it comes to changing between panels as such. But the issue that I am having is that 2when I press on a button I am not able to get the text of a label to change.

Code for now:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.Drawing.Text;

//Most of the following code works and does produce the window
//Having to work on converting from the Java coud that works to C#
//This is now working and continueing to build it up.

namespace unchained{
    public static class Program{
        public static void Main(String [] args){
            Form window = new();
            ...

            Button style = new();
            style.Text = "Style";
            style.Location = new Point(25, 25);
            style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            style.Click += (sender, e) => roleSelected(sender, e, "style");
            Label selectStyle = new();
            selectStyle.Text = charSheet.style;
            selectStyle.Location = new Point(25,325);
            selectStyle.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            
            ...
            
            window.Width = 800;
            window.Height = 600;
            window.Controls.Add(style);
            window.Controls.Add(selectStyle);
            Application.Run(window);

            void roleSelected(object sender, EventArgs e, string value){
                    Console.WriteLine(value);
                    newSheet.style = value;
                    selectStyle.Text = value;
                    Console.WriteLine(newSheet.style);
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

The Console log is to check that the value is being passed down and also into the second class that I had created so as to use as a temporary storage. I know that the data is being passed no problem but the label is not updating. Some other responses to this I have seen  are to use refresh on the label but I am unable to access the label as it is not initialized. But when I do that I get other issues.

So looking to see where I could be going wrong on this.

Thanks.

Comment: *"I am unable to access the label as it is not initialized"*. If that were really true then how do you expect to change the `Text`? The suggestion is to call `Refresh` AFTER setting the `Text`. What would be the point of doing it before the change? I doubt it's going to help but that's what you're being told.

Comment: What is `newSheet` and where is it declared? Are you seeing the change to its `style` refelected?

Comment: Here is the exact error that I am getting from the above code:
```
error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'selectSty 
le'
```
The newsheet is a 2nd class that I am using to store data so just has a bunch of strings and ints in it to be used across multiple panels.

I know it is working because the second console log prints from that. So i know the arg is being passed down and stored in the variable I want. From some odd reason it is just not updating the Label.